How to select an alternate application for a particular scheme or domain in Chrome
I'm on a Mac, and whenever I come across the tel: scheme, Chrome prompts me to open Facetime but doesn't give me an opportunity to select an alternate application. Firefox, does, which makes me think this is a browser setting rather than an OS one, but one or the other might hang off associations in the OS.
Additionally, I want to be able to launch other applications based on other criteria of the URL -- all Facebook URLs should open in firefox, all .onion URLs in Tor, etc.
Is this achievable? Either in a particular browser like Chrome or across the board (Chrome/FF/Brave/Tor/etc)?
